# When an R vector function call has an error, which element caused it?

Tags: r, debugging, vectorization, posixct

I have a long vector of date strings that I want to convert to POSIXct objects. When I call as.POSIXct I get this error:
`Error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`
How do I find which element of the vector caused the error? For example, what would tell me the error in the following code was caused by the second element:
`as.POSIXct(c('2015-12-10', 'aaa', '2015-12-11'))`?

==============

Edit: I'm looking for an answer that's general to vectorized functions in R, as.POSIXct is just an example. In general, when `f(x)` encounters an error, which element of `x` caused it?

Comment: As far as I know, the internals of many vectorized functions won't be able to be exposed to an R user. You could try `?debug` and running through a function if it's written using R code, or use `lapply` to apply a vectorized function one-by-one on a vector and see where the result is unexpected or NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a format explicitly to the `as.POSIXct()` call, you will get `NA`s returned when a proper date(time) isn't passed in:

```
as.POSIXct(c('2015-12-10', 'aaa', '2015-12-11'), format="%Y-%m-%d")
#[1] "2015-12-10 EST" NA               "2015-12-11 EST"
```

Comment: I edited my original question to clarify, but what I'm looking for is a general way of finding which element in a vector produced the error. Thanks for the response.